# maximum number of ports in a Verilog module or a VHDL entity

Tags: vhdl, verilog, hdl

Just out of curiosity, is there a constraint on the maximum **number of ports** in a Verilog module or VHDL entity imposed by their standards?

Comment: In the VHDL language there are no limits on the number of ports. There can be limits in target devices or synthesis tools. Your question sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), perhaps you can describe what you're trying to do that you have a concern.

Answer (score 6):

The SystemVerilog [LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) says, in 23.2.2 Port declarations

> Implementations may limit the maximum number of ports in a module
>   definition, but the limit shall be at least 256.

The Verilog LRM says the same thing in 12.3.3 Port declarations.

Realistically, unless you are using some sort of code generator (or you like typing a lot) you are unlikely to exceed this limit.